# ORACLE FORMS builder

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

i'm having a problem when trying to MAXIMIZE ORACLE forms builder's window ; i've tried all the right commands ( set_windw_property ) also i've edited the formsweb.cfg file (width , hieght and separate) .
Can anyone help me with such an issuse ??

Kindly note that i'm using - Forms [32 Bit] Version 10.1.2.0.2 (Production); on windows 7 .

Comment: To clarify, are you trying to maximize the window during development or during actual use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried setting the MDI properties?

> On MS-Windows, Forms run inside a
>   Windows Multiple-Document Interface
>   (MDI) window. You can use
>   SET_WINDOW_PROPERTY on the window
>   called FORMS_MDI_WINDOW to resize this
>   MDI (or any other named) window.

```
set_window_property(FORMS_MDI_WINDOW, WINDOW_STATE, MAXIMIZE);
```

Source: http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Forms_FAQ

Comment: IT WORKED WITH ME AFTER I HAVE MODIFIED THE FORMSWEB FILE....I was working the whole time on another path that refers to an old developer's version that was installed time a go :S 
Many thanks everyone for your concern :)